# About modulus of a vector in a vector lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, vector-lattices

A real vector space $E$ is said to be an **ordered vector space** whenever it is equipped with an order relation $\ge$ that is compatible with the algebraic structure of $E$.

A **Riesz space** or vector larttice is an ordered vector space  $E$ which for each pair of vectors $x,y \in E$, the supremum and the infimum of the st $\{x,y\}$ both exist in $E$.
Following the classical notation, we shall write
$$x \vee y := \sup \{x,y\} \quad , \quad  x \wedge y := \inf\{x ,y \} \quad , \quad |x|=x \vee (-x).$$

A Riesz space is called **Dedekind complete** whenever every nonempty bounded above subset has a supremum .

Here $\mathcal{L}_b(E,F)$ is the vector space of all order bounded operators from $E$ to $F$.

An operator $T:E \to F$ between two Riesz spaces is said to be **regular** if it can be written as a difference of two positive operators. Of course this is equivalent to saying that there exists a posiive operator $S:E \to F$ satisfying $T \le S$.

By **"postive operator"** book of "Charalambos D.Aliprantis and Owen Burkinshow" we have the following theorem

> Theorem(F.Riesz-Kantorovich)
>   . If $E$ and $F$ are Riesz spaces with $F$ Dedekind complete, thenthe ordered vector space $\mathcal{L}_b(E,F)$ is a Dedekind complete Riesz space with the lattice operations $$|T| = \sup\{\|Ty\| : \|y\|\le x \},$$ $$ [S \vee T](x)=\sup\{S(y)+T(z) : y,z \in E^+ , y+z=x\} ,$$ $$  [S \wedge T](x)=\sup\{S(y)+T(z) : y,z \in E^+ , y+z=x\}$$ for all $S,T \in \mathcal{L}_b(E,F)$ and $x \in E^+$.

Now I want to prove the following exercise :

> Consider the continuous function $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined by $g(x)=x$ if $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ if $\frac{1}{2} < x \le \frac{1}{2}$. Now define the operator $T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ by $[Tf](x)=f(g(x))-f(\frac{1}{2})$. Show that $T$ is a regular operator whose modulus does not exist.

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: I can show that $T$ is regular. Actually my question is about the second part of question. For the second part I think, first I must assume that there exists modulus $|T|$ and this makes a contradiction by regularity of $T$, but I don't know how I can make this contradiction.